# lxc-start: failed to spawn

Tags: lxc

I tried following the steps to create and start an lxc container from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html

My host is running an up to date 64-bit Precise (12.04), and I'm trying to start a precise containers. I created the container like this:

```
sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n precise -- -r precise
```

and it seemed to complete succesfully. When I try and start, I get:

```
$ sudo lxc-start -n precise
lxc-start: failed to spawn 'precise'
```

and kern.log says:

```
Sep 27 09:27:15 hans kernel: [3738467.397433] device vethrtJYFO entered promiscuous mode
Sep 27 09:27:15 hans kernel: [3738467.399113] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethrtJYFO: link is not ready
Sep 27 09:27:15 hans kernel: [3738467.409192] init: Failed to spawn network-interface (vethLNDNFP) pre-start process: unable to change root directory: No such file or directory
Sep 27 09:27:15 hans kernel: [3738467.412190] init: Failed to spawn network-interface-security (network-interface/vethLNDNFP) pre-start process: unable to change root directory: No such file or directory
Sep 27 09:27:15 hans kernel: [3738467.413059] init: Failed to spawn network-interface (vethLNDNFP) post-stop process: unable to change root directory: No such file or directory
Sep 27 09:27:15 hans kernel: [3738467.417246] init: Failed to spawn network-interface (vethrtJYFO) pre-start process: unable to change root directory: No such file or directory
Sep 27 09:27:15 hans kernel: [3738467.419247] init: Failed to spawn network-interface-security (network-interface/vethrtJYFO) pre-start process: unable to change root directory: No such file or directory
Sep 27 09:27:15 hans kernel: [3738467.420327] init: Failed to spawn network-interface (vethrtJYFO) post-stop process: unable to change root directory: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the package `cgroup-lite` is not installed. Try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cgroup-lite
$ sudo cgroups-mount
```

And run the container again.

Comment: Seems to work. Bug in the deps of some package?

Comment: @NeilenMarais lxc doesn't depend on cgroup-lite, but recommends it (or cgroup-bin).  That could be the problem.

Comment: I had completely different stuff in kern.log, but installing `cgroup-lite` helped me as well. Thanks!