# Ubuntu cgroup architecture: cgroup-lite vs cgroup-bin and default config for lxc, libvirt-bin?

Tags: lxc, cgroup

It seems that (at least in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise), the cgroup-lite package is used to provide some cgroup capabilities for packages like libvirt-bin and lxc.  It sets up a number of cgroups in /sys/fs/cgroup for example.

I was reading the very nice [documentation on cgroups for redhat](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html) and I wanted to use some of the other cgroup commands that are only in cgroup-bin.  But when I installed that, /sys/fs/cgroup became empty, presumably because the cgroup-lite package was uninstalled since it conflicts with cgroup-bin.

What am I missing after having done this?  Is there a way to get the same default set of cgroups that cgroup-lite sets up?  Is there any documentation for the cgroup definition that cgroup-lite provides?

The [lxc documentation in the server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html) talks a bit about cgroup-lite, but seems to assume that cgroup-lite will be installed, which won't be true if either recommended packages are skipped, or the alt]ernative, cgroup-bin, is installed.

Comment: I've seen some bugs that may be related, such as [lxc-start: failed to spawn](http://askubuntu.com/a/385929/6130)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the same cgroup management files just by adding the `/cgroup` mount to your fstab:

```
cgroup          /cgroup         cgroup  defaults        0       0
```

The files end up in a slightly different location. With `cgroup-lite`, you will end up with paths like `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.shares`, whereas with the fstab method you'll get `/cgroup/cpu.shares`.

The `cgroup-lite` package itself is just providing an init script to mount those control directories if they don't yet exist via fstab or some other means.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good!